# Angular 2 app-root never routing to page. (After page refresh)

Tags: angular, router

The app will sometimes stick at the index.html after a refresh. And never routes to the correct route. 
My index.html Looks like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
//links
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

My app component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

And this is my RouterModule.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path:'', redirectTo:'/login', pathMatch:'full'
      },
      {
        path:'login',
        component:LoginPage
      },
      {
        path:'test',
        component:TestPage,
        children:[
          {
            path:'question/:id',
            component:QuestionPage
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path:'admin',
        component:AdminLoginPage
      },
      {
        path:'adminhome',
        component:AdminPage,
      },
      {
        path:'admintest/:id',
        component:AdminTestPage
      }
```

The app works fine after a ng build. But once I refresh the screen it sometimes sticks on this page: [image]

And I can't fix it unless I preform another ng build.  Any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: Look at your console, definitely, there is an error!

Comment: Most the times it happens there are NO console errors. But sometimes it gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined. After a new ng build that goes away though.